# Generating LaTeX style scatter plot diagram using R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to generate a Latex diagram (a scatter plot) using ggplot2 in R.

Original image:

[image: original]

Code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1.5,1.5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2.5,3,3,3,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5,5.5,5.5,5.5,6,6,7)
                 ,y = c(1,1.5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2.5,2.5,3,3,3,3,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,4,4,4,4.5))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.3)
```

What I obtain:

[image: my plot]

Comment: What do you mean by "Latex like diagram"? Do you just want to produce a plot like you showed above? :)

Comment: yes, I mean just the diagram with points oriented as in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround would be:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point(col = "blue", size = 5) +
        theme_minimal() +
        labs(x="", y="") +
        annotate(geom = "text", x = 1, y = 5, label = "y") +
        annotate("text", x = 7, y = 1, label = "x") +
        theme(axis.line.y = element_line(arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.4, "cm"))),
              axis.line.x = element_line(arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.4, "cm"))))
```

[image]

Comment: I'd add `labs(x='', y='') + theme(plot.text = element_text(family='Computer Modern'))` provided you have that font installed

Comment: @Álvaro I agree. But what did you mean by `plot.text`? I get this error when I add your `plot.text...` suggestion: `Error: Theme element plot.text is not defined in the element hierarchy`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. To change the font of the axis labels it should be `theme(axis.text = element_text(family='Computer Modern'))`, whereas to change the font of the additional 'x' and 'y' labels you should add the argument `family='Computer Modern'` to each  `annotate()` call

Comment: Also, if you want to make an exact copy and include all numbers in the x axis, you should add `scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:max(df$x))`

Comment: Is it possible to get the points oriented as in the original picture?

Comment: @Raj can you please clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: I mean the topology of the points. In the original image, the ordering of the points is a little different.  Or maybe should I check the points from my end?

Comment: @Raj I have not changed anything in your data. I only plotted it. So the way your points look is the way they are supposed to look :)

Comment: Oh, I see, My points are somehow got shuffled. Thanks for the assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this which very nearly gets you all the way there:

- Times New Roman type face
- italicised axis titles
- ragged grid
- aspect ratio = 1

Shortfalls:

- the "stealth" arrow head
- axis tick marks above as well as below axis lines

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1.5,1.5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2.5,3,3,3,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5,5.5,5.5,5.5,6,6,7)
                 ,y = c(1,1.5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2.5,2.5,3,3,3,3,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,4,4,4,4.5))

library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)

# helper dataframe for axis
df_arrow <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0),
                       y = c(0, 0),
                       xend = c(0, 8),
                       yend = c(8, 0)) 


ggplot(df,aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 5)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:7, expand = expansion(add = c(0, 1)))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:7, expand = expansion(add = c(0, 1)))+
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 7), ylim = c(0, 7), clip = "off")+
  geom_segment(data = df_arrow, aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = yend), size = 0.75, colour = "black",
             arrow = arrow(angle = 20, length = unit(3, "mm"), ends = "last", type = "closed"), linejoin = "mitre") +
  annotate("text", x = c(7.8, 0.3), y = c(0.3, 7.8), label = c("italic(x)", "italic(y)"), parse = TRUE, size = 6,  family = "Times New Roman")+
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray80"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(1, "mm"),
        text = element_text(size = 18,  family = "Times New Roman"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>